# Cannot redeclare function() with recursion inside for loop

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have PHP code that looks like this:

```
function generate_sections() {
    $puzzle = [];

    // sections
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        // cells
        function generate_cells() {
            $section = [];

            for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
                $random_number = rand(1, 9);

                if (!in_array($random_number, $section)) {
                    array_push($section, $random_number);
                } else {
                    return generate_cells();
                }
            }
        }

        array_push($puzzle, $section);
    }

    return $puzzle;
}

var_dump(generate_sections());
```

The second for loop has to generate unique numbers and add them to the sections[] array. This works fine when I take the second for loop out of the first one. However, when writing it like this, the generate_cells() function doesn't recur, it gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare generate_cells() (previously declared in /Applications/AMPPS/www/sudoku/index.php:38) in /Applications/AMPPS/www/sudoku/index.php on line 37
```

Comment: It's because you're trying to re-declare generate_cells , you need to put that function outside of generate_sections, then just call generate_cells INSIDE generate_sections

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. The code declares the function in a loop, again and again. A single declaration is enough and a second one is not allowed.

Comment: @clearshot66 I see. But the weird thing is that I just made a function that was not inside a loop, and within that function I was able to call itself by using 'return function_name()'. Why can't I execute the function inside itself in this case? I need the recursion to happen inside that else statement, otherwise the logic is gone.

Comment: You attempt to declare the function 9 times but you don't call it even once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declareting function "generate_cells" in loop. At second loop executing, when function is allready declareted you getting a fatal error.
It's must be like this:

```
function generate_sections() 
{
    $puzzle = [];

    // sections
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        // cells
        $section = generate_cells();

        array_push($puzzle, $section);
    }
    return $puzzle;
}

function generate_cells() 
{
    $section = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $random_number = rand(1, 9);

        if (!in_array($random_number, $section)) {
            array_push($section, $random_number);
        } else {
            return generate_cells();
        }
    }

    return $section;
}

var_dump(generate_sections());
```